# SQL One-to-one relationship join

Tags: sql, left-join, inner-join

I have 2 tables one is an extension of the other so it is currently a simple one-to-one relationship (this is likely to become one-to-many in the future). I need to join from one table to another to pull a value out of another column in the extension.

so table A contains basic details including an id and table B uses a FK reference to the Id column in table A. I need to pull out column X from table B.

To add complexity sometimes there won't be a matching entry in table B but in that case it needs to return null. Also the value of X could be null.

I know I can use a left outer join but is there a more efficient way to perform the join?

Comment: You just described exactly what a left outer join is for.

Comment: Perfect thank you for the confirmation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left outer join is the way.  In order to make it most efficient, make sure you index the FK column in table B.  It will be super-fast with the index.

You don't need to index the primary key in table A for this query (and most databases already index primary keys anyway).

The MySQL syntax for creating the index:

```
CREATE INDEX `fast_lookups` ON `table_b` (`col_name`);
```

You can name it whatever, I picked "fast_lookups."